# Does 当たりめーだろ equal to 当たり前だろ but slang?

Tags: translation

Recently met this phrase several times in the context like affirmative or positive answer.
Googling it didn't help muchб and it doesn't look like typo too.
For me it looks like まえ rather naturally transforms to めー here, so I think it's probably some kind of slang, isn't it?